# Having issues installing pipenv

Tags: pip, pipenv

I am new to python with an accounting experience so I am starting off my journey learning to code with python.

I am having issues installing pipenv and I have referred to Github and other sites to see where I went wrong. this is what comes up when I am installing pip install pipenv,

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103b0ac90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10382e600>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103f2cc50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103f2ce60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103f2d070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')': /simple/pipenv/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv

Any help would be amazing with this thank you

I have tried following some suggestions from others on discussion boards but I have not had any luck.